# How to prevent Less from trying to compile CSS calc() properties?

Tags: css, compilation, less, css-calc

The [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) compilers that I'm using ([OrangeBits](https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/OrangeBits) and [dotless 1.3.0.5](https://github.com/dotless/dotless)) are aggressively translating

```
body { width: calc(100% - 250px - 1.5em); }
```

into

```
body { width: calc(-151.5%); }
```

Which is obviously not desired. I'm wondering if there is a way to signal to the Less compiler to essentially ignore the attribute during compilation. I've searched through the Less documentation and both compilers' documentation, and I could not find anything.

Does Less or a Less compiler support this?

If not, is there a CSS extender that does?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a compiler less agressive?

Comment: I am very sure too, to want the compiler be more aggressive! (the double negation in the previous comment confused me ;) ) (so my vote as well for the nice feature below)

Answer (score 557, accepted):

Less no longer evaluates expression inside `calc` by default since [`v3.00`](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300).

---

***Original answer (`Less v1.x...2.x`):***

Do this:

```
body { width: calc(~"100% - 250px - 1.5em"); }
```

In Less 1.4.0 we will have a `strictMaths` option which requires all Less calculations to be within brackets, so the `calc` will work "out-of-the-box". This is an option since it is a major breaking change. Early betas of 1.4.0 had this option on by default. The release version has it off by default.

Comment: Note that if you're compiling less with twitter's recess it [ignores this escaping](https://github.com/twitter/recess/issues/59). At least at the time of writing this comment.

Comment: I just tried `calc(100% - 50px)` in less.css 1.4.0 and the result was `calc(50%)`. The awesome `~"..."` trick continues to work, but I am confused by the "out-of-the-box" statement, which makes me think the above would work. Luke, how does support for `calc` change in Less 1.4.0? Thanks!

Comment: The question is why did less.js attempt to compute this in the first place? It should throw an error for "100% - 250px" as it can't compute a sensible answer.

Comment: **Update:** I see there's a `--strict-units` option which prevents these kinds of errors. Awesome!

Comment: Does this still work? I'm when trying with `calc(~"100% + 20px");` the compiled css is `calc(120%);` note: I am using grunt to build the less and js files

Comment: For future readers, you can also escape just the operator, enabling you to use variables as well. Example: `calc(@somePercent ~"-" @someLength)`

Answer (score 39):

A very common usecase of calc is take 100% width and adding some margin around the element.

One can do so with:

```
@someMarginVariable = 15px;

margin: @someMarginVariable;
width: calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
```

Comment: `-o-calc-` [is not supported yet](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp).

Answer (score 34):

There is several escaping options with same result:

```
body { width: ~"calc(100% - 250px - 1.5em)"; }
body { width: calc(~"100% - 250px - 1.5em"); }
body { width: calc(100% ~"-" 250px ~"-" 1.5em); }
```

Answer (score 11):

There's a tidier way to include variables inside the escaped calc, as explained in this post: *[CSS3 calc() function doesn't work with Less #974](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/974)*

```
@variable: 2em;

body{ width: calc(~"100% - @{variable} * 2");}
```

By using the curly brackets you don't need to close and reopen the escaping quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
@variable: 2em;

body{ 
    width: ~"calc(100% - @{variable} * 2)";
}
```

Reference: [Is there a way to use variables in Less for the ~ operator, like ~"calc(100% - @spacing)";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279328/is-there-a-way-to-use-variables-in-less-for-the-operator-like-calc100)