# Is there a way to use variables in Less for the ~ operator, like ~"calc(100% - @spacing)";

Tags: css, less, css-calc

Is there a way to use variables in less `~` operator, like

```
~"calc(70% - @spacing)";
```

When I have tried it it only works with static values like

```
 ~"calc(70% - 10px)";
```

Can I get the string to be evaluated prior to beeing set as a property.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

To disable the calculation which LESS does automatically when discovering a `-` between two numeric values but still being able to use variables, you can write one of the following:

1) Only escape the operator that triggers the calculation and use the variable like you normally do

```
@padding: 20px;
body {
    padding: calc(100% ~"-" @padding);
}
```

2) Escape the whole expression and interpolate the variable with the `@{padding}` notation

```
@padding: 20px;
body {
    padding: ~"calc(100% - @{padding})";
}
```

I prefer the second version, since it resembles [javascript's template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and looks a bit cleaner, but either way works just fine.

Both solutions disable the automatic Less calculation and compile to the correct result:

```
body {
  padding: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: This was enlightening