# Sidebar menu with scrollbars hiding dropdowns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar menu with dropdowns and a long list that needs a scroller.

The issue I'm having is either the scrollbar is off the screen or the dropdown is hidden because of `overflow: hidden;` or both.

Here is my CSS:

```
/* I want dropdowns to be on the left */
 .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: -160px;
}
#rightbar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 300px;
}
/* Normally, you'd do this, but this makes the dropdown not show; ALSO, the scrollbar is off the screen */
 #wrap {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bottomStuff {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp0fqyt9/

*How do I get dropdowns and scrollbars to work in a `position: fixed` sidebar (without JS)?*

Comment: #wrap {height:100%; overflow:hidden;} overflow hidden here is hiding the dropdown

Comment: I know, but how do I get the `bottomStuff` wrapper to be 100% height of whatever is left on the screen... that doesn't sound possible without JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `#bottomStuff { height: 100% }`. `height: 100%` represents the height of the viewport, but `#bottomStuff` is offset from the top because of `#topStuff` and `hr`, therefore the element is extending beyond the height of the viewport.

(Let's say your browser is 500px high, then `#bottomStuff` is 500px high, but if `#topStuff` is 100px high, only 400px of `#bottomStuff` is visible in the viewport, and the bottom 100px is not visible because it extends beyond the viewport, and you'll never see the overflow because of `position: fixed`)

If the browsers you need to support support CSS3’s `calc()` (You can check browser support for `calc()` at http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), you can use it like this if you know the height of `#topStuff + hr`:

```
#bottomStuff {
    height: calc(100% - 200px); /* Where 200px is the height of #topStuff + hr */
}
```

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/xo1z0yyg/

Comment: Good solution, and you can use JavaScript to calculate height of the topStuff and set CSS to bottomStuff (if your topStuff is dynamic) something like this: height: calc(100% - topStuffHeight)

Comment: So, this keeps giving me `height: calc(-100%)` because its treating the PX as % in the calc function.

Comment: @Jeff Does the browser you're testing this on support CSS3's `calc()`? If you check the demo link in Chrome or a modern browser it works as expected.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Here's an example `height: calc(100% - 10px);` gives me   `height: calc(90%);` I figured out 'why' but not a fix... I'm using less. less is doing the math before the css can.

Comment: Can you make a demo or show me a screenshot of how you know Chrome is calculating the height as `calc(90%)`? I can't replicate your issue. When I put in `calc(100% - 10px)`, Chrome's inspector is properly calculating the height. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/vRzgyeb.png

Comment: In less, you have to escape the calculation so that css3 will do it instead of less: `height: ~"calc(100% - @{rightbarTopCombinedHeight})";`  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279328/is-there-a-way-to-use-variables-in-less-for-the-operator-like-calc100) showed me.

Comment: Ah, then it’s a LESS issue and not a CSS issue. Not sure. I tried your solution with escaping calc and it worked fine for me.