# Web Essentials 2013 bug while compiling calc() property in LESS

Tags: compiler-errors, less, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2013 in Visual Studio 2013, and when I use `calc()` property in LESSCSS it compiles it incorrectly.

Let's see:
[image: web essentials calc bug while compiling less]

So, it must compile it as is and must not do math calculations into calc scopes.

Comment: The output is exactly what I would expect. What output are you expecting?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11972084/2712740

Comment: @NikaTomadze LESS does its compilation first, the output of that is in the CSS. If you want to make LESS ignore a string that looks like LESS might compile it you need to escape it.

Comment: @DeanTaylor as usually less doesn't compile strings in calc(), I'm using another compiles also when using Less as NPM, only VS does so..

Comment: @NikaTomadze it's all down to the version of LESS and the options enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem's solved, thanks [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max)

> See [Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11972084/2712740)