# How to use calc function in less

Tags: css, less, css-calc

I want to use calc function in less. My required output should be `right: calc(-100vw + 400px);`. Therefore I used below code in less.

```
right: calc(~'-100vw + 400px');
```

But that code is not working. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `right: ~"calc(-100vw + 400px)";` - That should be the correct syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Less, CSS3 calc() doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353427/using-less-css3-calc-doesnt-work-correctly)

Comment: your answer is here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973298/11954917