# Is it possible to use vh minus pixels in a CSS calc()?

Tags: css, less

I have following CSS rule in a Less file:

```
.container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```

Which doesn't work at all. I want to make container full window height and minus header, footer fixed height.

How can I do that?

Comment: Seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/gz4zp1ua/2/

Comment: Make sure the browser in question actually supports what you're asking for:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc and http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.

Comment: I had closed this as a dupe because that thread has details about updated options also which could be useful for others (on top of it, that question also has higher views and vote counts).

Comment: If you're using less variables you can use something like this:
calc(~"100vh" - (**@first-header-height** + **@second-header-height**));

Answer (score 295, accepted):

It does work indeed. Issue was with my less compiler. It was compiled in to:

```
.container {
  min-height: calc(-51vh);
}
```

Fixed with the following code in less file:

```
.container {
  min-height: calc(~"100vh - 150px");
}
```

Thanks to this link: [Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc)

Comment: Bitten by this. In case you need to use variables inside the string, you can do ti like this: `calc(~"100vh - @{navbar-height}")`

Comment: Perfect trick, thanks to you ! Wondered why it works in .css but not in .less

Comment: this also seems to work   `calc(~"100vh - "@bar-height)`  using LESS

Comment: ow man why no one pointed out that we need spaces on both sides of `-`, now it works

Comment: @mkb Thanks, Chromium told be my property was invalid because of missing spaces.

Comment: In SASS/SCSS it would be: `max-height: calc(100vh - 150px)`. Cheers!

Comment: @mkb thanks a lot.
In my case chromium is not working with double quotes. I used
min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);

Comment: One can use it with various sizes as well, like:

`.container { min-height: calc(100vh - 2em); }`