# Overflow: hidden not working with full viewport sections

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a set up with several sections that have a full-screen width and height. Whether I position them absolute or relative the overflow still doesn't work.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vdghk7u6/)

```
section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#a {
  background: linear-gradient(1deg, #9f00b8, #2a032d);
  position: absolute;
}

#b {
  background: linear-gradient(1deg, #25cc00, #2a032d);
  left: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the overflow still doesn't work"?

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do? do you want only one section to be visible? or something else ...

Comment: I don't want it to be able to scroll. I want to use a jquery animate to get to the other section, I don't want it to be viewable otherwise.

Comment: Use width: calc(100% - Xpx); ,  height: calc(100% - Xpx);

Comment: @DevStud could you supply a small demo, I've never worked with calc

Comment: @Shniper I think you wont this: https://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/vdghk7u6/2/

Comment: @DevStud it works in your example and even when I upload my code to a fiddle it works, but when I have it in my root files and open in browser it doesn't. https://jsfiddle.net/3twg23ya/

Comment: So maybe you need to add some browser support for calc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111155/discussion-between-shniper-and-devstud).

Answer (score 1):

Change your `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;`

Like this:

```
width: 100%;
height: calc(100% - 0px);
// height: 100vh;
// width: 100vw;
```

And change the following line:

```
#b {
  background: linear-gradient(1deg, #25cc00, #2a032d);
  //left: 100vw;
   left: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

So i think calc is your solution maybe there are some other solution. Now you need browser support for calc.

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 0px);
width: calc(100% - 0px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 0px);
height: -moz-calc(100% - 0px);
height: calc(100% - 0px);
```

I hope it will help.

Working **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/vdghk7u6/3/)**

If you want to use vh with calc() you can check this answer [It is possible to use vh minus pixels in a CSS calc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256849/it-is-possible-to-use-vh-minus-pixels-in-a-css-calc)

Comment: @Shniper i hope it will help.