# Is it possible to combine 'px' and 'vh' into the height of 1 component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a few components and some of them are sized with px.  The others I want to be variable size.  However, the ones that are variable size are not a constant percentage of the page because of the components with a fixed px height.  So I want a component to be about 80% of the screen height('80vh') minus the height of the other component.  I was hoping to use something like

```
style={{height:'80vh-40px'}}
```

but that does not work.

I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256849/it-is-possible-to-use-vh-minus-pixels-in-a-css-calc) which gets close but that my program does not recognize that calc function. Do I need to require it from some library maybe?

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: calc() works in css. So i would build a class that does the calc() and apply that class to your component via className="yourCalcClass"

Comment: That seems like a great solution.  I must admit that I do not know how to create a css class in a react component.  I will do some research and figure out how that is done.  thanks!

Comment: its just regular css class in a css file and you apply the class with className= instead of class=

Comment: and include that class as a style sheet in your .html file?  that is what I am doing right now and it is not working for me.  I created a .css file and put this in it:

calcHeightClass {
  height: calc(~'85vh - 75px');
  margin-top:'1vh';
  overflow-y:'scroll';
}

then my componenet looks like this

<Col className='calcHeightClass' sm={3} md={3}>....no luck.  It is not styling it at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use syntax like this in my React.js components:

```
<div style={{height: 'calc(100vh - 400px)'}}></div>
```

it works for me.

Inside CSS code with LESS preprocessor I use the same syntax, but not equal:

```
.right_col {
  height: calc(~"100vh - 400px");
}
```

In my experiments, I found that symbol "~" doesn't work in React.js components.

Comment: `height` prop doesn't exist and doesn't work

Comment: @TomSawyer, you are right. It was just an example. But I've changed it to the real syntax with `style` attribute to avoid misconception. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A way to solve it is by using **style={}** in your component.

```
const styles = {targetDiv: { height: 'calc(100vh - Xpx)'}}
```

then...

```
<div style={styles.targetDiv}>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note - you can get the window.innerHeight (see http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ for height and width options in javascript) and just calculate this yourself in react and set the width or height in pixels.

If you do this with height, you'd need to recalculate if it changes

```
state = {
  windowHeight: window.innerHeight
}

componentWillMount () {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
}

handleResize = () => {
  this.setState({ windowHeight: window.innerHeight })
}
```

in your div

```
<div style={{height: this.state.windowHeight}} > ... </div>
```

You wouldn't want to do this everywhere, but it's very handy for some situations.  For example - setting 100% height on Android mobile web, where 100vh does not work and device buttons cover up part of the screen.