# ReactJS - ant design - Fix Footer with Layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, antd

I am using ant design framework in my project with reactjs. I am trying to achieve a layout design in which the footer should stick to the bottom of the screen and header fixed to the top, only content should resize it should look like

```
--------------------------------
|          HEADER              | 
--------------------------------
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
| LIST  |       CONTENT        |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
--------------------------------
|          FOOTER              | 
--------------------------------
```

Below is my live example what I am trying to do

https://codesandbox.io/embed/j4rkr509o3

I am not sure how to make it work, it would be very kind if any one can help me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe ant supports this automatically, but you can just set the height of the content div to be 100vh - (header.height + footer.height). So in your example something like this:

```
<Content>
   <div style={{ background: "blue", height: "calc(100vh - 55px)" }}>
      text
   </div>
</Content>
```

Comment: I had tried to use `calc` but somehow it was deducting `50vh` than `50px`.

Comment: Are you defining the height inline or in your less file? If via less, it could be you're having the problem reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256849/it-is-possible-to-use-vh-minus-pixels-in-a-css-calc. The answer has a simple fix.

Comment: Yes I am using `.less` I will try the solution, thanks.

Comment: I had to do `minHeight: ...` to support pages larger than the browser window.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this formula works like a charm: `100vh - (header.height + footer.height)`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}` for Layout component. Works for me. For example like this:

```
  <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
    <Header>Header</Header>
    <Content>Content</Content>
    <Footer>Footer</Footer>
  </Layout>
```

Comment: your example is really helpful for me when I was stuck in setting the footer at the bottom of the content 
Thanks,

Comment: This solution works well when the virtual keyboard shows up.

Answer (score 9):

You can try adding `position: sticky` to your `<Header>` and `<Footer>`, and specify the location (i.e. `top, bottom`) you want them to stick to.

To achieve your goal, you can try:

`<Header style={{ position: "sticky", top: "0" }}>`

`<Footer style={{ position: "sticky", bottom: "0" }}>`

Hope that helps, cheers :)

Comment: `position: sticky` is no go if you want IE support

Comment: @Yichaoz if you want IE support, another way I can think of is to use `position: fixed`. However by doing so, you'll have to do some additional styling to get to the desired look.

Answer (score 2):

you can add  `{{position: 'sticky'}}` and place the Footer outside of the Content

[here is an example with sticky footer](https://react-d61z7s.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Sider` for side bar and set `position: absolute` to the main layout with 100% height and width

Here
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vw98316zn)

Also it was not working the layout component because you did not include antd.css for codesandbox

Comment: It does solve, but I want the content to scroll within the screen above footer, and footer not to go out of screen, thanks for pointing out `antd.css` I was wondering why it doesn't render.

Comment: that will be completely different solution, since the footer doesn't know if the body has overflow or not. you will need to layout manually without using Layout component, and set  content container to  <div style={{ minHeight: "calc(100vh - 70px)" }}> . where 70px is the height of the footer + header. but calc() is only supported  IE11 +

Comment: Thanks, for reply I am not worried about IE right now, I tried to use calc to determine the height of the content, but there seems to be problem with this as in your case it turns to 30vh as it takes `70px` as `vh` not `px` which changes the whole thing. Can you put more light into it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own sticky footer https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Then populate the rest of your site with AntD components.