# React mixing units error: Can't calculate vw and px together in css calc() function

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, typography

I want to make my font size fluid using css calc() in React but it keeps throwing error when I mix units vw and px.

```
font-size: calc(14px + (26px - 14px)) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300));
```

Got an error and SASS can't compile 100vw - 300px.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: This isn't using CSS `calc`, it's using SASS `calc`.

Comment: SASS can't compile `100vw` though, it must just pass it through. `100vw` is a value that _cannot_ be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In a CSS `calc`, the multiply or divide operators must have a unitless number as one of the operands.

[The MDN Docs say:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

> * Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a `<number>`.
>
> / Division. The right-hand side must be a `<number>`.

Your multiplication violates this rule. Simplified it's this:

```
calc(26px * (100vw - 300px) / 1300);
```

This is illegal because neither `26px` or `(100vw - 300px)` are unitless numbers.

---

You also have an extra close parentheses after `14px)` that makes this a syntax error as you have written it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would help if you told us what the error was, but you could try:

```
("100vw - 300px")
```

See more here [Is it possible to use vh minus pixels in a CSS calc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256849/is-it-possible-to-use-vh-minus-pixels-in-a-css-calc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using css custom property (css-variable) might work for you:

Woking with a css-variable kind of hides the value and its unit(works at least for attributes like width or height). Or wrap again everything in a calc.

```
section {
   --viewWidth: 100vw;
   font-size: calc(14px + (26px - 14px)) * ((var(--viewWidth) - 300px) / (1600 - 300));
}
```