# how to get width of screen and add some value to it in css

Tags: html, css

I want to get the screen size and add **253px** to it
Or something like this in **css**

```
width: (100% + 253px)
```

how can I make this happen?

Comment: `width: (100vw + 253px)`, but if you add `body { margin: 0 }`, then your rule `width: (100% + 253px)` works like `width: (100vw + 253px)`

Comment: .container {
  min-height: calc("~100vh - 150px");
}

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256849/is-it-possible-to-use-vh-minus-pixels-in-a-css-calc)

Comment: @MiladJurablu, you are asking about the `width`, but agree with the `min-height`. How can it be?

Answer (score 1):

tnx to my freind **Alenx**

```
.container { min-height: calc("~100vh - 150px"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set width and height relative to the viewport.
with vh, vw

There you can add an offset in px with the following line of code.

```
.container { min-height: calc("~100vh - 150px"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS to measure a percent of the window screen and add to or cut from that amount in a pixel scale, you'll need to hit `ElementSelector { width: calc(100% - 253px) }` in your CSS (without "calc" function, that math calculation can't be computed since they're of different scales).