# CSS calc() to subtract px from % is interpreting px value as a %

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in a container with a 1px border. I want each div to take up exactly half of the container by width, so I'm trying use CSS3's `calc`
function to subtract a predetermined pixel value (2px, one border line on each side of the divs) from the overall width (50%). However, for reasons I can't figure out, it's subtracting a percent value from the percent value instead of a pixel for this operation: `calc(50% - 2px);`

Here is the relevant styling for the divs in the container:

```
.contained {
  border-width: 1px;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any preprocessor?

Comment: Ah, yes I'm using LESS and using webpack to load it into my JS

Comment: Then you have to use it escaped, because of some LESS parsing, like so: `~"calc(50% - 2px)"`, otherwise LESS will not render the syntax correctly. Your syntax is basically correct, just not in LESS.

Comment: This isn't relative to calc() but its not even necessary in this case. You could use `box-sizing: border-box` instead.

Comment: I like that - what's industry standard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by CKH4 use `box-sizing: border-box` instead. [`box-sizing`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) is better supported than [`calc`](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) and it's neater and more flexible too.

```css
.contained {
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone has down voted. Whoever did, I would love to hear what is wrong with this answer.