# Doing a very specific equation with calc in less

Tags: less, calc

I need to do a very specific equation using calc in less.

Namely this

```
padding: 0 calc((100% - 1280px)/2 + 30px);
```

It works perfectly when i try it in the editor in chrome but i'm not sure what parts of the equation need to be encapsulated in ~"".

Currently i'm doing the below but it doesn't yield the correct sum

```
padding: 0px ~"calc((100% - 1280px)/2 + 30px)";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Less and calc

try:

```
padding: 0px calc(~"100% - 1280px)/2 + 30px");
```

Its a some what known issue with [less](/questions/tagged/less):
**[Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc#11973298)**