# How Calc() calculate in css?

Tags: css, less, calc, css-calc

Can somebody describe Use of `Calc()` in css?
And what is `~` sign meaning with `Calc()`?

How below code calculate?

```
calc(~'(100% - 4 * 23.233%) / 3')
```

Comment: That's the [general sibling combinator]. You can't use it like that, it's invalid. Unless you are using some preprocessor.

Answer (score 7):

That is not a valid value in plain CSS.

It looks like that is from [LESS source code](http://lesscss.org/), which is compiled down to the following:

```
calc((100% - 4 * 23.233%) / 3);
```

As stated by the [relevant LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping), `~''` is used for escaping:

> Escaping allows you to use any arbitrary string as property or variable value. Anything inside `~"anything"` or `~'anything'` is used as is with no changes except [interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation).

This is done to prevent LESS from automatically evaluating the expression as math. Without the escaping, the value would be evaluated and compiled to:

```
calc(2.3559999999999994%);
```

For further reference, see this related question: "[Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc)".