# System.Web.Optimization StyleBundler removes space from infront of + but not - when compiling and minifying less

Tags: css, less, bundler, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

When using plain CSS calc in less I have to put a tilde before my calc string to stop less from calculating it, which works when doing - but does not when using +

What causes this and can I stop it from happening?

Examples:

```
width: calc(~"(100%) - 20px");
```

Results In:

```
width: calc((100%) - 20px);
```

But:

```
width: calc(~"(100%) + 20px");
```

Results In:

```
width: calc((100%)+ 20px);
```

Which is not valid css.

The only workaround I have figured out is:

```
width: calc(~"(100%) - -20px");
```

Results In:

```
width: calc((100%) - -20px);
```

Which is mathematically correct to do a + but why do the Bundling and Minification force me to have to do this?

As a side note, I use visual studio 2017 community and its bundling from the bundleConfig.cs

My style bundle looks like so:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/BundledCSS")
            .Include("~/Content/css/UpToDate/jquery-ui.css")
            .Include("~/Content/less/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/font-awesome.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/animate.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/SidewaysNav.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/site.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/pastel-colors.css")
        );

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        bundles.FileSetOrderList.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084

Comment: As for removed whitespace, [it's not Less doing this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%20%7B%5Cn%5Cta%3A%20calc(~%5C%22(100%25)%20-%2020px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%20%20%5Ctb%3A%20calc(~%5C%22(100%25)%20%2B%2020px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) (but most likely some  css-minifier sitting after Less). Less itself should never touch anything inside `~""` (see [the definition](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping)) except certain specific markers.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my question to help point it more towards the bundling and minification side of things