# CSS variable with calculation inside LESS

Tags: css, less

I have a CSS variable called `--menuWidth`.  I'm trying to use this variable with an arithmetic operator but I'm having trouble.

I tried the following:

```
left: calc(var(--menuWidth) + 20px);
```

But the `less` processor output says "OperationError: Operation on an invalid type" (at column 2?)

I found [this working codepen](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/WbwJyg) which actually seems to confirm the syntax above, so I'm assuming this is a LESS issue.  If so, how can I fix it?

---

Here is my file structure:

**vars.less**

```
:root {
    --menuWidth: 200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px){
    :root {
        --menuWidth: 250px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    :root {
        --menuWidth: 300px;
    }
}
```

**layout.less**

```
#headerContainer {
    left: calc(var(--menuWidth) + 20px);
}
```

**compiled.less**

```
@import "vars.less";
@import "layout.less";
```

Comment: To be clear, I have already removed the operation and set a left-margin of 20px which I know fixes the issue, but I want to know how to do this for future usage.

Comment: CSS variables aren't interoperable with LESS.

Comment: Update to Less v3 or higher or (if you have to use earlier versions) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913203.

Comment: You linked to *this* question. :)

Comment: My bad, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084 or any of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating LESS from 2.7.2 to 3.0.4 fixed the issue.