# Percentage as the final output in LESS and Calc()

Tags: css, less

I have 25 divs side by side.

The first div needs to be 200px. The next 24 divs need to be divided equally in the remaining screen space available, so 100/24, which is 4.16%.

I need the css for the 24 equal divs. How do I calculate this using calc?

Here's the pseudocode of what I need, but LESS doesn't seem to recognize the outside %.

```
calc((100% - 200px) / 24)%
```

Comment: no need for the outside % which is invalid ... `calc((100% - 200px)/4)` is enough

Comment: I actually tried that but it doesn't work. Inspecting it shows that it evaluates to this: width: calc(-4.16666667%)

Comment: you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer my original question...it only talks about the negative percentage...

Comment: try it and see .. you need to use this `calc((100% - 200px)/4)` and avoid less to evaluate it (like in the duplicate) .. you said *that it evaluates to this: width: calc(-4.16666667%)* which means that you have a compilation issue, not calc() issue

Comment: Where are you getting 4 from? Do you mean 24?

Comment: yes sorry I mean 24 ... your formula without the % at the end

Comment: I tried it...the result is all divs squished together...

Comment: did your try what suggested in the duplicate `calc(~"(100% - 200px)/24")` ?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't use flex here?

Comment: Well, in case you didn't find the answer you were hoping for, here's a fiddle with the flex solution: [flex 25 items](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/8xof6sL4/)